# How to retrieve the documents whose values ending with a particular character in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I inserted the documents into a particular database in mongoDB.
for example

```
 db.employee.insert({name:"nithin",age:22})
 db.employee.insert({name:"sreedevi",age:32})
```

now i wnat to retrive the documents whose name ending with character '**i**'.

Comment: You can do this with regex.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In Javascript shell, use [$regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/) operator

```
db.employee.find({name: {$regex: "i$"}})
```

Comment: +1 You can add `find(...).pretty()` for a better arrangement.

Comment: its easy using $regix

    db.employee.find({name:/i$/})

if i want to find the name starting with i use 

    db.employee.find({name:/^i/})

Comment: With `^` you can have the advantage of your indexes, and thats why $regex is worth using in such cases. A suggestion you might want to consider, avoid adding features like "name ending with char" since they eat up unnecessary RAM and isn't scalable.